# Matrix multiplication in Node.js with multithreading?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, performance, matrix

I know this is a strange thing to do but I just want to know if it's possible.

Can you get real performance gains in Node.js for processor heavy computations if you used node's cluster module or some other multithreading / multiprocess module? Note: this is a client side only program (No network stuff).

For example, I tried making a matrix multiplication program in node.js using the cluster module where I assigned each process a row of the answer to calculate. However because node.js prevents sharing memory, I have to rely on message passing to send the large calculated rows back to the parent process. This was way slower than just performing the matrix multiplication serially. Maybe I'm just doing something wrong or I have a bad strategy but I'm just curious if anyone else has been able to operate on large pieces of data with node.js and really use the full power of their processor. If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: you need to balance cpu time with network io. one row per thread is bad, but try breaking the image up into 8 stripes and crunching each stripe on a different process. it still might be quicker to use one thread: certain problems lend themselves to MP more than others: ideally you have a small work description that takes a long time and returns a small payload.

Comment: There are better parallel matrix multiplication algorithms where one divides both matrix in like four parts - top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right. However, the network would always that much more time.

Comment: Now this is going to make this question seem even more weird. I'm using Node.js client side only with no network stuff at all. Now before you say, "you should be using C or C++ with pthreads." Again I'm just curious if there is an example of doing a heavy computation on a large amount of data with Node.js. Think like CUDA type problems. So far I'm under the impression that this is impossible to do because message passing large data around will always be the bottle neck and make it super slow. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JXcore](http://jxcore.com) (a node.js distro) is currently your best bet for cpu heavy operations with node.js. It has multithreaded tasks support with a visible performance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me. This page: http://jxcore.com/docs/jxcore-store.html really clears things up for me - a thread safe shared memory store. I think that will really speed things up. I will now test out some multi-threading and see if I can beat a serially executed algorithm.

Comment: hey @KylePaulsen did it work for you? I'm just curious about the possibility of using nodejs for matrix operations.

Comment: web site link is broken. try https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore .